# Relation between second derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In attempting to find a relation between second derivatives of $\frac{dx}{dy}$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$, I used the relation:

$\frac{dx}{dy} \times \frac{dy}{dx}$ = $1$

Then I differentiated both sides with respect to $x$ giving, using product rule and chain rule:

$\left(\frac{dy}{dx} \times \left(\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}\times\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\right)$ + $\left(\frac{dx}{dy} \times \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)$ = $0$

Thus $(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 \times \frac{d^2x}{dy^2} =  $-$\left(\frac{dx}{dy} \times \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)$

Which gives:

-$\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)$ = $(\frac{dy}{dx})^3 \times \frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$

But apparently the answer is:

-$\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)$ = $(\frac{dx}{dy})^3 \times \frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$

Am I wrong in applying the chain rule there? Or is there another mistake?

Comment: $-\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)=(\frac{dy}{dx})^3 \times \frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$ is the correct answer. So $\to +1$.

Comment: Ah. Not a good book then. Thank you.